# How to create Magento Order programatically in Amazon M2epro

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, controllers, m2epro

I want to create magento order from Amazon M2Epro Extension in magento 2.

I am able to create Order Object but not sure how can I call Controller function CreateMagentoOrder()

Git Link - https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension

Controller path - https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Amazon/Order/CreateMagentoOrder.php

Code -

```
$id = '9302';
$amazonobj = $objManager->get('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Amazon\Order');
$order = $amazonobj->load($id);
print_r($order->getData());

$order->createMagentoOrder();  // Not Working
```

Anyone please explain how to call controller function from external php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this one

```
$force = 'yes';

$amazonFactory = $objManager->create('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Component\Parent\Amazon\Factory');
$order =$amazonFactory->getObjectLoaded('Order', (int)$id);
$order->getLog()->setInitiator(\Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Data::INITIATOR_USER);

if (is_null($order->getMagentoOrderId()) && $force == 'yes')
{
     // Create magento order
        // ---------------------------------------
        try {
            $order->createMagentoOrder();
          echo 'Magento Order was created.';

        // Create invoice
        // ---------------------------------------
        if ($order->getChildObject()->canCreateInvoice()) {
            $result = $order->createInvoice();

        }
        // ---------------------------------------
        // Create shipment
        // ---------------------------------------
        if ($order->getChildObject()->canCreateShipment()) {
            $result && $this->messageManager->addSuccess($this->__('Shipment was created.'));
        }
        // ---------------------------------------
        // ---------------------------------------
        $order->updateMagentoOrderStatus();




        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            /**@var \Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Exception $helper */
         'Magento Order was not created';

        }
}
```

Comment: can I use this in external php script? I dont want to do anything in Module itself.

Comment: Ya,  sure  you  can use

Comment: I am sorry to asking your help in such a way here. Please can you guide me on this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7